# Error when passing struct to function in c

Tags: c, gcc, struct, parameter-passing

When I pass a struct to a function, I get the error: expected ‘struct book’ but argument is of type ‘struct book'. Why is this happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct book
{
    int id;
    char title[50];
};

int showBooks(struct book x);

int main()
{
    struct book
    {
        int id;
        char title[50];
    };

    struct book book1,book2;

    book1.id = 2;
    book2.id = 3;

    strcpy(book1.title, "c programming");
    strcpy(book2.title, "libc refrence");

    printf("Book\t\tID\n");

    showBooks(book1);
    showBooks(book2);
}

int showBooks(struct book x)
{
    printf("%s\t%d\n", x.title, x.id);
}
```

The error:

> 30:12: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘showBooks’
>   showBooks(book1);
>
> 10:5: note: expected ‘struct book’ but argument is of type ‘struct
>   book’  int showBooks(struct book x);
>
> 31:12: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘showBooks’
>   showBooks(book2);
>
> 10:5: note: expected ‘struct book’ but argument is of type ‘struct
>   book’  int showBooks(struct book x);

where the error here?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: gcc version 6.3.0

Comment: Why do you have two definitions of book? Delete the one inside main. https://ideone.com/RIgIYH

Comment: Unrelated to the redefinition of book, the showBooks() function should return void.

Comment: lol, I love error-messages like this, (not really). The compiler should make it more obvious that the names might be the same, but the type records are different.  Users look at such errors and think that the compiler has had a tequila too many:(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your two different struct definitions define two different types. Even though they are both called `struct book`, they are not the same type.

Your variables `book1` and `book2` have a type of the local struct, but the function expects a struct of the type of the global struct, hence the error.

You could fix the problem by deleting the local struct definition; then `book1` will have the type of the global struct etc.

Comment: Congratulations on 100k!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler and still learning... while checking the standard about this answer, I discovered that a local struct in one TU can be compatible with a global struct in another TU  (so , `struct book` in another TU could be compatible with both of the `struct book`s in this code, even though those two are not compatible with each other!).

Comment: The cross-TU structure compatibility rules are intriguing — and crucial when you think about it.  Yes; the problem is that the 'inner' `struct` is different from the 'outer' one simply by being a new definition (though `struct book;` in the function would also hide the 'outer' definition too).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler so it would actually be possible to pass `book1` to `showBooks` -- if we go via a function in another translation unit

Comment: I don't think you're intended to get away with it, but you probably would in practice.  The main rules are in C11 [§6.2.7 Compatible type and composite type ¶1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.7) and [§6.7.2 Type specifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2), especially [§6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1).  Where would you declare the external function prototype? It will take one of the two types, and the other is not the same.  However, I suspect compilers would have little reason to go looking for the subterfuge.

Answer (score 3):

A local variable or parameter that hides a global variable of the same name. This may be confusing. The "struct book" inside the main() hides  the global definition of the "struct book".
The variables book1 and book2 are the type of "struct book" with local reference to the main().
The showBooks() use arguments as the book1 or book2 as formal parameters.
The actual parameter uses the global definition of the "struct book" which results in incompatible type.
Comment the local definition and find the difference.